# Using accumulative sum on ordered MDX query

Tags: ssas, mdx

I have an MDX query That is sorted and I want to add an accumulative sum column.

The problem is that when I use an aggregate function, it still sum the values in default order, not the order I specified.
below is my MDX query:

```
WITH 
  MEMBER RunningTotal AS 
    Aggregate
    (
      {
          [Dim Product].[ProductName].FirstChild
        : 
          [Dim Product].[ProductName].CurrentMember
      }
     ,[Measures].[Sales Amount]
    ) 
SELECT 
  {
    [Measures].[Sales Amount]
   ,RunningTotal
  } ON 0
 ,NonEmpty
  (
    Order
    (
      [Dim Product].[ProductName].[ProductName]
     ,[Measures].[Sales Amount]
     ,Desc
    )
  ) ON 1
FROM [InternetSales];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is your query - you mention a 'specified order' but I cannot see one:

```
WITH 
  MEMBER RunningTotal AS 
    Aggregate
    (
      {
          [Dim Product].[ProductName].FirstChild
        : 
          [Dim Product].[ProductName].CurrentMember
      }
     ,[Measures].[Sales Amount]
    ) 
SELECT 
  {
    [Measures].[Sales Amount]
   ,RunningTotal
  } ON COLUMNS
 ,NON EMPTY 
    [Dim Product].[ProductName].[ProductName] ON ROWS
FROM [InternetSales];
```

As an example I think if you'd like to order the rows by Sales Amount then you could introduce an `ORDER` function:

```
WITH 
  MEMBER RunningTotal AS 
    Aggregate
    (
      {
          [Dim Product].[ProductName].FirstChild
        : 
          [Dim Product].[ProductName].CurrentMember
      }
     ,[Measures].[Sales Amount]
    ) 
SELECT 
  {
    [Measures].[Sales Amount]
   ,RunningTotal
  } ON 0
 ,NON EMPTY 
    Order
    (
      [Dim Product].[ProductName].[ProductName]
     ,[Measures].[Sales Amount]
     ,BDESC
    ) ON 1
FROM [InternetSales];
```

---

Example against AdvWrks:

```
WITH 
  MEMBER RunningTotal AS 
    Aggregate
    (
      {
          [Product].[Category].FirstChild
        : 
          [Product].[Category].CurrentMember
      }
     ,[Measures].[Sales Amount]
    ) 
SELECT 
  {
    [Measures].[Sales Amount]
   ,RunningTotal
  } ON 0
 ,NON EMPTY 
    Order
    (
      [Product].[Category].[Category]
     ,[Measures].[RunningTotal]
     ,BASC
    ) ON 1
FROM [Adventure Works]
```

Returns the following:

[image]

---

An alternative that gets around the ordering inherited from the cube is the following:

```
WITH 
  SET X_UNORDERED AS 
    {
      NonEmpty
      (
        {[Product].[Category].[Category].MEMBERS}
       ,[Measures].[Sales Amount]
      )
    } 
  SET X_ORDERED AS 
    {Order(X_UNORDERED,[Measures].[Sales Amount])} 
  MEMBER [Measures].[Rank] AS 
    Rank
    (
      [Product].[Category].CurrentMember
     ,X_ORDERED
    ) 
  MEMBER [Measures].[RunningSum] AS 
    IIF
    (
      [Measures].[Rank] = 1
     ,[Measures].[Sales Amount]
     ,
        [Measures].[Sales Amount]
      + 
        (
          [Measures].[RunningSum]
         ,X_ORDERED.Item(
          [Measures].[Rank] - 2)
        )
    ), FORMAT_STRING="$#,#.00"
SELECT 
  {
    [Measures].[Sales Amount]
   ,[Measures].[RunningSum]
  } ON 0
 ,X_ORDERED ON 1
FROM [Adventure Works];
```

Returns the values in the order you want:

[image]

Comment: I don't know why I forgot to add order in my query. Thank you so much, I edited my post. The problem is that the running total column should have an ascending order since the new Sales Amount is added to the previous value but, when you run this query the running total column is not based on the new Sales Amount order.

Comment: did you try `BDESC` or `BASC` ?

Comment: Yes, they don't affect the result of the accumulative sum, it seems it is based on the default order.

Comment: if you use Order
    (
      [Dim Product].[ProductName].[ProductName]
     ,[Measures].[RunningTotal]
     ,BASC
    ) instead?

Comment: Thank you for the answer but, I use `[Dim Product].[ProductName].[ProductName] ,[Measures].[Sales Amount] ,BASC`. the order of results should be on Sales Amount column.

Comment: ok - so you need it ordered by sales amount and the running total should follow that order - think I understand the requirement now

Comment: Added a further, slightly more complex script which does want I think you need?